# Tkinter not starting a window

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I'm making a basic chat client in Python, but it won't open the window. It seems to freeze when the server thread is started. I'm using the `socketserver` module.

```
class ChatClient(Frame):
    def CreateWidgets(self):
        self.whoislist = Label(self,text = '')
        def updateWhoIs(peopleList):
            finishlist = 'People:'
            for person in peopleList:
                finishlist += ('\n' + person)
            self.whoislist.config(text = finishlist)
        self.whoislist.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 7)
        self.mainchat = Text(self)
        self.mainchat.grid(columnspan = 5, rowspan = 3, row = 2, column = 3)
    peeps = []
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.CreateWidgets()
        print('Huh.')
        self.server = socketserver.TCPServer(('127.0.0.1',1337),MyTCPHandler)
        self.sthread = Thread(target = self.server.serve_forever())
        self.sthread.start()
        print('Yay')
```

Comment: You can only use tkinter commands in the thread that the root window was created in.

Comment: @BryanOakley perhaps but this is a separate and quite common issue. (see my answer)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why I pinged you for that.

Answer (score 1):

you call `self.server.serve_forever()` while initializing the thread, setting its return value to the target of the thread, however as the name implies: it lasts forever.  Instead specify the method (without calling it) as the target:

```
self.sthread = Thread(target = self.server.serve_forever)
```

and it should work although be careful how `MyTCPHandler` interacts with the Tk application as tkinter is not thread safe.